# Use of next.config.js with expressjs

Tags: next.js

1) It is mentioned in [next.js docs](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#custom-server-and-routing) that we can start our server with `next start`. Is that as same as just `next`?

2) When we use custom server implementation mentioned [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#custom-server-and-routing), the debugger breakpoint is stopping at `next.config.js` also. As far as i understood from [this blog](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-build-a-server-rendered-react-app-with-next-express-d5a389e7ab2f/), `next.config.js` is for URL mapping to generate static site. So, why `next.config.js` is also being used here?

Any link for understanding next.js overview/architecture is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Is that as same as just next?

No, `next` will start the application in dev mode.

`next.config.js` is a normal node module for custom and avanced behavior of Next.js, so in that case, as explained in the docs, you are telling next application **to not** serve each file in `/pages` under a pathname matching the filename.
Best link for understanding next.js is their official [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs)

Answer (score 0):

According to my test runs and understanding, in `next.config.js` we can specify plugins and `exportPathMap` for build
so even if we are using custom server, we need `next.config.js` to do work such as transpiling typescript, compiling/minify sass files etc.

`next start` pre-requisites is `next build` which generated `.next` directory with build files. it will serve the build files unlike `next` which is local dev server with HMR

But, I am yet to find any documentation to understand the complete architectural flows of the framework